# Persisting a JsonElement into a single table column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gson

(It seems to me that this question should have been already asked somewhere, but I just can't find it, so excuse me in advance if it's a duplicate)

I am using Hibernate and Gson. Say, I have an object like this

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    ...
    com.google.gson.JsonElement bar;
    ...
}
```

`Foo.bar` can be of arbitrary format. That's why I need to persist it in a single database field, i.e. I need to serialize it, presumably to JSON, and persist that string into the `bar` column of my `foo` table. Currently, unsurprisingly, I just get an error from Hibernate because the `JsonElement` type doesn't map to the string-type database column. How can I achieve this mapping (using Hibernate or, more generally, JPA)?

Comment: You have `@AttributeConverter` allowing you to convert any type to some persistable type.

Comment: Thank you, that's it :)! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the `JPA 2.1` `@AttributeConverter` and can then convert the `JsonElement` into `String`. It is also fully portable across other JPA providers should you ever need to use those